# получить код html страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.5

я хочу скачать код html страницы но не знаю как ниже приведен код который мне не подходит ведь он скачивает саму страницу , а мне нужен код как при нажатии CTRL + U в Гугл Хром

```
def down():
    resp = req.get(site)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    with open('site.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: Вам нужен код что javascript-движок использует

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать библиотеку [requests_html](https://github.com/psf/requests-html), чтобы выполнить js-код на странице.

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/3b46bf2235a72fa6dbf2b92ed7cfc6afedc28940/requests_html__examples/save_before_after_js/main.py#L16)

```
# pip install requests-html
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
rs = session.get('https://coronavirus-monitor.ru/statistika/')
with open('rs_before_js.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(rs.html.html)

rs.html.render()  # Без этого не будет выполнения js кода

with open('rs_after_js.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(rs.html.html)
```

Comment: Мне нужно что бы все пробелы остались а при таком сохранении они сбиваются как и при моём коде, нет ли другого способа?

Comment: @krime, не понимаю о каких пробелах вы имели ввиду. Если те, что между тегами, то они не имеют значения, а если те, что внутри, то это сомнительно, т.к. они имеют значение и парсер их не должен трогать. А в вашем коде вы делаете ненужную работу, используя парсер. Если вам нужно просто сохранить страницу, то: `with open('site.html', 'wb') as f: file.write(resp.content)`. Если я неправильно понял, то поясните в вопросе что значит `код как при нажатии CTRL + U в Гугл Хром`: отформатированный, исходный, или отрендеренный (пропущенный через js)